# Concatenation doesn't work in phpmyadmin XAMPP

Tags: mysql

I tried to use "||" for concatenation:

The query I used:

```
"SELECT id, name, age, age||id FROM myTable;"
```

This is the output:

[image]

Can anyone tell me why the output is not 201 (in first column) and 162(in second column)?? Also it gives similar outputs when I use two attributes that are of varchar datatype and the above two attributes are of int datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Can anyone tell me why the output is not 201*

**its because, in mysql, you need to enable `PIPES_AS_CONCAT`.** in order to work with `||`

> If the `PIPES_AS_CONCAT` SQL mode is enabled, || signifies the
> SQL-standard string concatenation operator (like CONCAT()).

You can set it using phpmyadmin->variables->searchFor SQL_MODE

[image]

Refer [mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat)

But i would suggest you to use

```
CONCAT(columnName1, columnName2, ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such concatenation in mySQL. This is Oracle SQL dialect. You have to use the CONCAT function in mysql

```
SELECT id, name, age, CONCAT(age,id) FROM myTable
```

Comment: `There is no such concatenation in mySQL` No its not true. You can use || for concat if you enable it in SQL MODE

Comment: @IndraKumarS Yes you are right. Never mentioned that because I always want to make my queries as much easy to be transferred to other dialects as possible

Comment: Its a users choice. You cannot say that it doesnt exist in mysql

Answer (score 0):

visit the Mysql [Documentations](https://dev.mysql.com) :
on this link you will find a list of **[String Functions and Operators](https://String%20Functions%20and%20Operators)**

but you not use|| to concatenate caratcters or strings but do this :

1. `SELECT id, name, age, concat(age,id) FROM myTable;` or
2. `SELECT id, name, age, concat_ws(' ',age,id) FROM myTable;` if you want to space the age with id like this for example 23 1. 23 for age and 1 for id.